# Create matrix with count of consecutive strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe made of two columns with strings in it, as follows:

```
word 1   word 2
cat      dog
dog      mouse
mouse    dog
dog      dog
dog      mouse
mouse     ...
```

What I would like to do in python, is build a matrix that counts how many times a word follows another, as this:

```
       cat   dog   mouse
cat     0     1      0
dog     0     1      2
mouse   0     1      0
```

What I have tried so far was tokenization (but it may not be the best approach) and computing a matrix correlation (but apparently `pandas.DataFrame.corr` does not work with strings).

Do you have any idea on how to proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.crosstab` and `reindex` to ensure having all combinations:

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.unique(df.values.flatten())

(pd.crosstab(df['word 1'], df['word 2'])
   .reindex(index=idx, columns=idx, fill_value=0)
)
```

output:

```
word 2  ...  cat  dog  mouse
word 1                      
...       0    0    0      0
cat       0    0    1      0
dog       0    0    1      2
mouse     1    0    1      0
```

*NB. `...` appears here as a the word due to your example*